# Editing content from admin of Drupal website is not reflecting changes in front end simultaneously.

Tags: php, drupal-6

I am administering a drupal website. The website is in two languages with separate databases and admin panels. When i update or add content of English website from admin panel it reflects the changes next day. I have also tried to edit content directly from database but it was not reflected simultaneously. Also i edited the page.tpl file of my theme but changes are not reflecting on front end. Its driving me crazy. Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do You clear all caches? Or the site is located in the cdn network?

Comment: Thanks Shoshin! Clearing Drupal Cache solved the issue.